# uniform convergence of sequence of ceiling function on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$, let $f_n(x) = f(\lceil nx \rceil / n)$, I know that $f_n$ converge point-wisely to $f$ but does $f_n$ necessarily uniformly converge to $f$? any proof or justification is appreciated.

Comment: It depends on how $f$ is defined. For $f_n(0)\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow f(0)$ while $f_n(1)\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow f(1)$. These need not be the same.

Comment: Could you give me an example that fn not uniformly converge to f？